# Обновить форму Django

Tags: python, django

У меня есть двухстраничный сайт, который отображает таблицу из БД. Сайт позволяет добавить информацию о сотруднике и обновить некоторые поля.
Я столкнулся с проблемой, что когда хочу обновить поле с всплывающим списком "Департамент" (данноe поле является ForeignKey), выкидывает ошибку ValueError (Cannot assign "'Департамент сервиса'": "Employee.department" must be a "Department" instance.).

[image: Первая страница сайта, которая отображает таблицу из БД]

[image: Вторая страница сайта, где можно обновить данные]

views.py

```
def edit_department(request, id):
try:
    dep = Department.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        dep = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
        dep.department= request.POST.get("department")
        dep.save()
        return redirect("base")
    else:
        return render(request, "manager_employees/edit_department.html", {'dep': dep})
except Employee.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponseNotFound("<h2>Person not found</h2>")
```

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="ФИО")
date_of_start = models.DateField(verbose_name="Дата оформления")
position = models.ForeignKey("Position", on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Должность")
department = models.ForeignKey("Department", on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Подразделение")

class Department(models.Model):
department = models.CharField(verbose_name="Наименование департамента", max_length=50, db_index=True)
```

template.py

```
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <label>Введите отдел</label><br>
        <select name='department'>
            {% for key in dep %}
               <option value="{{ key }}">{{ key }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" >
</form>
```

Возможно ли в данной ситуации как то исправить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

логично. Employee.department - это ключ, а вы пытаетесь ему присвоить строку из POST.
Для начала вам надо получить объект department и его уже присваивать. Т.е. как-то так:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        dep = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
        instance = get_object_or_404(Department, department=request.POST.get("department"))
        dep.department= instance
        dep.save()
        return redirect("base")
```

Код не проверен, но должно быть примерно так.

И по вашему шаблону. Искать по тексту это немного моветон. Рано или поздно встретится модель, где будет несколько записей с одним текстом. Старайтесь использовать id в передаваемых параметрах

```
<select name='department'>
            {% for key in dep %}
               <option value="{{ key.id }}">{{ key.department }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

Comment: Tatarincev Это то что надо. Спасибо огромное, уже не первый раз выручаете начинающего разработчика!